# Pug / Jade : Render a string variable of pug formatted text within .pug template file

Tags: express, pug

I have passed an object to my pug template which contains a property which is a string of pug formatted text.

`data.pugtext` is `'p span This is a test.'`

I want my pug template to render this variable but can't seem to figure this out. If I `include data.pugtext` it errors out saying data.pugtext file is not found. If I do `#{data.pugtext}` is does not render but simple passes the string as is to my client.

Anyone know how to render a string variable containing pug formatted text inside a template.pug file?

Comment: I don't think pug is designed to parse strings into pug while compiling. Can you write that string to a file before compiling and then reference it with an `include`?

Comment: @sean I may have to... [Tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) seems to be what I am sort of looking for but I'm still fighting with it.

Comment: Tag interpolation only works for a single tag and not its contents, attributes or children. I don't think that will get you what you want unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried using mixins? Ideally your data would just include text content, not any tags or templating. You could pass that text content to a mixin